# Update FrontLine for tree like structure

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

I have a table like

```
ID | ParentID |FrontLine| Name | Address
----------------------------------------
1  | Null     |        | Xyz  | Home
2  |   1      |        | ABC  | Home
3  |   2      |        | DEF  | Home
4  |   3      |        | GHI  | Home
5  |   3      |        | GHI  | Home
```

I need to fill the FrontLine with a query. For example FrontLine for 1 will be 2,3,4,5 and FrontLine for 3 will be 4,5

So the table after query should look like

```
ID | ParentID |FrontLine| Name | Address
----------------------------------------
1  | Null     |2,3,4,5 | Xyz  | Home
2  |   1      |3,4,5   | ABC  | Home
3  |   2      |4,5     | DEF  | Home
4  |   3      |Null    | GHI  | Home
5  |   3      |Null    | GHI  | Home
```

How can I do this with a MySQL query?

Comment: can you post, what you have tried so far, as your question raises many other questions

Comment: Actually I am not proficient in writing queries. I have tried using subqueries but was not even near to it

Comment: have you tried UPDATE query to fill FrontLine column ?

Comment: Yes I have used UPDATE but I am not getting the conditions to apply :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do this in one update query. MySQL does not handle tree structure queries. (Oracle has `connect by prior` and `start with`  to organize the structure but MySQL can't do this).

I would write a stored procedure which execure itself recoursively updating one level each time and increasing the `FrontLine` value.